# Load SQL file into postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function

i'd like to load a local file and execute it in postgresql function but i dont know how..

i got a table which has only 1 column contains absolute file path like↓

```
tmp_import_files.filename
-----------------
/tmp/test_file.sql
/tmp/test_file1.sql
/tmp/test_file2.sql
-----------------
```

and want to make function something like this..

```
FOR rec IN SELECT filename FROM tmp_import_files ORDER BY filename ASC LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE rec.filename
    FOR sql IN LOAD rec.filename LOOP -- LOAD is not right?
        EXECUTE sql;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

LOAD allows to load shared library code in the PostgreSQL executable: it does not allow to load SQL files.

To load and execute SQL files you could try to use psql \i command or system function pg_read_file (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) with more code.